# SLOT problem / C++

Tags: c++, qt, slot

Im trying to figure this error out. I have a simple application made with Qt Creator.

I have three buttons and 2 of them are not enabled. Then when push the first button i want to make them visible, but when i push the button, windows error occures : "program stopped working". the program compiles and does everything else.

```
QPushButton *dealButton = new QPushButton(tr("Deal cards"));
dealButton->show();

QPushButton *hitButton = new QPushButton(tr("HIT"));
hitButton->show();
hitButton->setEnabled(false);

QPushButton *standButton = new QPushButton(tr("STAND"));
standButton->show();
standButton->setEnabled(false);

...
connect(dealButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(dealCards()));

...
void MainWindow::dealCards()
{
hitButton->setEnabled(true);
standButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

thats the code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are re-declaring `dealButton` and the others in your constructor (or whatever function it is that has the `new` calls you're showing).

You should have in your class definition:

```
private: // probably
  QPushButton *dealButton;
```

And in your constructor or gui init code:

```
dealButton = new QPushButton(...); // note: not QPushButton *dealButton = ...
```

What you have now is creating a new variable called `dealButton` that is local to that scope (function). That variable is hiding (masking) the class's member.